# Pasing data/values

Tags: php, database

I have this search php code in which i made the formnumber into a hyperlink. All I wanna do is once i click a formnumber it will retrieve all ta data of tha click formnumber into the database and echos it.

```
$dbname = "vianney300";
$SRCHDATA = $_POST["srch"];
if($connection===FALSE)
        echo "<p> Connection Failed. ". mysql_error()."</p>";
    else{
            if(mysql_select_db( $dbname)===FALSE)
                echo "<p>Could not select database.</p>";
        }   
$query = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE LastName='$SRCHDATA'";
$result = @mysql_query($query);
if ($result===FALSE){
    echo "<p>Unable to execute query.</p>";
    }
else {
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))!==FALSE){
        echo "Form no: ";
        echo "<a href='individual.php'>{$row['FormNo']}</a></br>";
        echo "Last name: ";
        echo "{$row['LastName']}</br>";
        echo "First name: ";
        echo "{$row['FirstName']}</br></br>";
```

Comment: ok good what is the problem then?

Comment: i don't know how to send data of the clicked form number to the individual.php

Comment: you can send like this `<a href='individual.php?form_no={$row['FormNo']}'>{$row['FormNo']}</a></br>` and on individual.php file you can retrive using `$_GET['form_no']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send a form number to individual page then you have to do like this inside your while function :

```
echo "<a href='individual.php?form_no={$row['FormNo']}'>{$row['FormNo']}</a></br>";
```

And on individual.php you will retrieve form number using `$_GET['form_no']`

**individual.php**

```
<?php
  echo $_GET['form_no'];

  // Using this form number you can fetch the data from database

?>
```

Comment: @user3146700 you have to write the sql query using this form number in where condition

Comment: in my individual.php it says  Notice: Undefined index: form_no in C:\wamp\www\Vianney300\individual.php on line

Comment: @user3146700 paste again that echo code, I have had made a mistake on that now it is working. It should be like `echo "<a href='individual.php?form_no={$row['FormNo']}'>{$row['FormNo']}</a></br>";`

Answer (score 1):

You have made a small mistake on this line

```
echo "<a href='individual.php'>{$row['FormNo']}</a></br>";
```

it should be

```
echo "<a href='individual.php?formnumber={$row['FormNo']}'>{$row['FormNo']}</a></br>";
```

*ok.then what should i put to echo in the individual.php*

Thats another question really, but

code individual.php

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_GET['formnumber']) ) {
        echo 'Recieved parameter "formnumber" in the GET array = ' . $_GET['formnumber'];
    } else {
        echo 'No parameter passed';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Should I send an invoice, or a link to the PHP Manual?